# Identify/highlight the most significant digits/characters from data arranged in two columns using the Vim editor

Tags: vim, diff

Is it possible in Vim editor to identify or highlight a common sequence of characters/digits from data arranged in two columns?

For instance,

```
0.0470013487688 40989223   0.0470013487688 002292
0.0421698758 73493412044   0.0421698758 476354659
0.0417166986 15951258722   0.0417166986 257990344
0.04167166 8474116192737   0.04167166 69861257942
0.041667 018771432653979   0.041667 1666698611258
0.0416 78177953892309171   0.0416 667166666986111
0.04 4004728342134522001   0.04 16666716666669861
0.04 0846598100993794511   0.04 16666671666666699
```

The first location where the digits in the two columns are different is shown with a space.

The goal is to hightlight the most significant digits obtained in a computation (left column) with the respective exact values (right column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on source data like this:

```
0.047001348768840989223  0.0470013487688002292
0.042169875873493412044  0.0421698758476354659
0.041716698615951258722  0.0417166986257990344
0.041671668474116192737  0.0416716669861257942
0.041667018771432653979  0.0416671666698611258
0.041678177953892309171  0.0416667166666986111
0.044004728342134522001  0.0416666716666669861
0.040846598100993794511  0.0416666671666666699
```

the following pattern will match as many digits in the first column that are identical with the ones in the second column:

```
/^\(\S\+\)\ze\S*\s\+\1
```

This captures non-whitespace (`\S`; you can refine that part) characters, stops matching (`\ze`), but asserts that there must be possibly more characters, and then the same characters in the next column.

I hope this is what you meant; it wasn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: Ingo Karkat: what you have understood is what I meant. Thank you.